# Get the first value from a nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object called `allInvalidFields` which lists invalid fields under an identifier e.g `_0` or `_3`

The object could look like this

```
allInvalidFields = {
    "_0" : {
        0: input.foo,
        1: select.la
    }
    "_1" : {
        0: input.foofoo,
        1: select.lala
    }
}
```

But equally it could not have `_0` as the first key and could look like this:

```
allInvalidFields = {
    "_1" : {
        0: input.alice,
        1: select.bob
    }
    "_3" : {
        0: input.foo
    }
}
```

How can I get the **first** value from the **first** object in the list? So in the example above it would be `input.foo` or `input.alice` depending on which dataset was being searched.

Comment: What about sorting the keys and getting the first one?

Comment: The notion "first" explicitly does not  make sense with JavaScript objects. Properties are in no particular order. If you need predictable order, use an array.

Comment: @Pointy I am so stuck, because if I add to an array then I cannot use key and value pairs which I need e.g `_1` but if I add to an object then there is no first as you say. I'm totally lost. I have been trying to find a solution fr 5 days now.

Comment: This is not possible. Keys/properties/fields in a JavaScript Objects does not have any order. You cannot sort a javascript object as with an array.http://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/3359432

Comment: Well you can impose your own ordering on the property names by keeping them in an adjunct array in whatever order makes sense for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Inferred that the keys are in numeric order and prepended with "_".

Under these **assumptions** :

```
function first(obj,n){
  let smallest = Infinity;
  for(i in obj){
    console.log(i);
    let val='';
    if (i.toString()[0]=='_'){
      val = parseInt(i.toString().substring(1));
    }else{
      val = i;
    }
    if( val < smallest ){
      smallest = val;
    }
  }
  if(n>0){
     return first(obj["_"+smallest],n-1);
  }
  return obj[smallest];
}

first({"_0" : {
    0: "input.foo",
    1: "select.la"
},
"_1" : {
    0: "input.foofoo",
    1: "select.lala"
}},1); // input.foo
```

Comment: obj["_"+Object.keys(obj).map(el=>el=+el.replace("_")).sort()[0]][0]... a bit shorter

Comment: A bit more cryptic :-D Also, with mine, you can chose depth !

Answer (score -1):

You need something like this.

```js
var allInvalidFields = {
  "_0": {
    "0": "input.foo",
    "1": "select.la"
  },
  "_1": {
    "0": "input.foofoo",
    "1": "select.lala"
  }
};

var firstInput = Object.keys(allInvalidFields)[0];
console.log(allInvalidFields[firstInput][0]);
```

Comment: Please read this answer and correct your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/3359432

Comment: @NidhinDavid. here the OP is simply concerned about getting the first element - whatever it is - from the subarray - not necessarily the first one that was added to the subarray.

Comment: What I meant is that there is no such thing as 'first' or 'last' key in Javascript object. Thats what the link says.

Comment: I agree. But here the OP is asking for a random first element.

Comment: The OP has made text bold.

Answer (score -1):

```
Object.values(allInvalidFields)[0][0];
```

take the first value of the first property object.

Small note: having such keys like _1 is bad style...

Short version of programaths answer:

```
allInvalidFields["_"+Object.keys(allInvalidFields).map(el=>el=+el.replace("_","")).sort()[0]][0]
```

Comment: The problem is that there's no guarantee what that ordering will be. There'll definitely be a first value, but it may or may not be what the OP considers "first".

Comment: If you pull first field, then it may not always the same as js objects does not implement order for its keys/fields http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/3359432

Comment: Missing depth flexibility of my answer ;-)